# Copy odd numbers from array into another array

Tags: c#, arrays

Im new to programming and struggling with this task:

In array X [20] random numbers from 1 to 30 are entered, in array Y enter only odd numbers from array X.
Print down Y.

```
int[] x = new int[20];
Random rnd = new Random();
int counter = 0;
int[] y;

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    x[i] = rnd.Next(1, 30);

    if (x[i] % 2 !=0 )
    {
        y = new int[counter];
        counter++;
        y[counter] = x[i];          
    }
}

foreach (int number in y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Im having problems to fill Y array with odd numbers without defining length of Y, I tried with adding counter but getting some errors all the time,
 If someone can help me with some suggestions that would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Seems homework to me.

Comment: `y = x.Where(i => i % 2 == 1).ToArray();`

Comment: Why `y` is an *array* `int[]`? `List<int>` is by far a more convenient collection

Comment: @SamAxe well I don't know was it on purpose or no to tag `c#-2.0`, but anyway, there was no LINQ back then.

Comment: Its not homework, its just practicing to understand how to copy numbers from one array into another without defining length of second array.

Comment: @KacaMat So why you've tagged `c#-2.0`?

Comment: The important thing to know is that arrays are fixed size after they have been created, so you always need to know the required size of the array before you create it. `List<T>` is resizable, and it works by using an array behind the scenes which it replaces with a new array of a different size when it needs to grow (it creates a new bigger array, then copies the old array into the new one and then uses the new one instead).

Comment: @SamAxe edited the question and deleted that tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like homework, so I guess using a more appropriate collection such as a `List<int>` is out of the question, just as using Linq.

At `y = new int[counter];` you're reinitializing the array. This happens each iteration, so your final array only holds the latest added value, and all values before that will be set to their default: 0.

You could've seen this by debugging your code by setting breakpoints, stepping through the code and inspecting your variables. You could then also have provided a more proper problem description than "getting some errors".

If you know the input is never larger than 20, you can initialize the output array to the same size and keep a counter of how many values you copied (the latter of which you already do).

Then when printing, only print the elements up till that count with a `for` loop instead of `foreach`.

So something like this:

```
int[] x = new int[20];
int[] y = new int[x.Length];

Random rnd = new Random();

int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    x[i] = rnd.Next(1, 30);

    if (x[i] % 2 != 0)
    {
        y[counter] = x[i];
        counter++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(y[i]);
}
```

Comment: Error that im getting all the time is: 
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' -> at y[counter] = x[i]; part
Thanks

Comment: That's because arrays are zero-based and you increment the counter after resizing the array.

Comment: I tried to initialize Y to size 20, set up counter, but no idea how then to add odd numbers into Y array

Comment: Just like you do, `y[counter] = x[i]`. Then increment the counter.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you create a new `y` array **for each** odd number you find. You need to create the array only once and then fill it.

Since you don't know how many odd numbers there will be, I suggest to use a `List<int>` instead:

```
int[] x = new int[20];
Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> y = new List<int>(); // create the list before the loop


for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    x[i] = rnd.Next(1, 30);
    if (x[i] % 2 !=0 )
        y.Add(x[i]);  // add odd number to list
}
foreach (int number in y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See, In your case you are not aware about the number of odd numbers in that random array. so Array will not be a right choice here if you are following the current implementation. If you want the output as array, then Why not a simple LINQ with `Where` like [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RjCklu):

First you collect all random numbers to your array as you are doing currently:

```
int[] randomIntegers = new int[20];
Random rnd = new Random();        
for (int i = 0; i < randomIntegers.Length; i++)
{
    randomIntegers[i] = rnd.Next(1, 30);
}
```

Now you have the all random numbers in `x` now perform the following operation:

```
int[] oddValues = randomIntegers.Where(a=> a % 2 !=0).ToArray();
```